# apache private key encryption

Tags: encryption, ssl

I have a web server with SSL, and I was wondering if encrypting the private key on the disk ( -des3 flag when creating it) was really useful, or if setting permissions to 400 on it was enough? (If someone gains root access to the server I don't think it will be helpful in any way since he could do pretty much everything he wants)

Thanks,

Oli

Answer (score 1):

The important part is to set it to be readable only by root, so `root:root` and permission `400` is suitable.

The `-des3` option allows for encrypting the private key with a passphrase.  Doing this would mean that every time a web or mail server starts or restarts you must enter the passphrase.  This would be impractical for a server certificate.

If you don't want to use a passphrase to protect the private key then I don't believe there is any reason to use `-des3`.

Comment: ok thanks but does not using it makes the server "less secure"?

Comment: In theiry but it's a tradeoff with convenience.